# Get over 2 GB limit creating PDFs with ImageMagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick, limit

I am using `convert` to create a PDF file from about 2,000 images:

```
convert 0001.miff 0002.miff ... 2000.miff -compress jpeg -quality 80 out.pdf
```

The process terminates reproducible when the output file has reached 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB −1) with the message

```
convert: unknown `out.pdf'.
```

The PDF file specification [allows for ≈10 GB](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1041350#thread-post-4584031). I tried to pull more information from `-debug all`, but I didn’t see anything helpful in the logging output. The file system is *ext3* which [allows for files at least up to 16 GiB (may be more)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274390/28856). As to `ulimit`, `file size` is `unlimited`. `/etc/security/limits.conf` only contains commented-out lines. What else can cause this and **how can I increase the limit?**

ImageMagick version: 6.4.3 2016-08-05 Q16 OpenMP
Distribution: SLES 11.4 (i586)

Comment: Is it possible for you create two files with half the images (or whatever fits you best), and then merge them with pdftk?

Comment: Do you have any good reason for creating a > 2 Gb PDF file?  I fear that many PDF readers would crash attempting to open it.

Comment: Because your copy of ImageMagick has been compiled without Large File Support. Please file a bug - it's 2017.

Comment: @dr01: Why should they? Large File Support has been around since decades.

Comment: @MartinSchröder And yet some programs aren't able to handle files too large.  Anyway, I was curious about the reason of creating a 2-Gb (that is, ~150'000 A4 pages) PDF file.

Comment: @dr01: These programs need to be fixed. BTDT.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your limitation does not stem indeed from the filesystem; or from package versions *I think*.

Your 2GB limit is coming from you using a 32-bit version of your OS.

The option to increase the file would be installing a 64-bit version *if the hardware supports it*.

See [Large file support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support)

> Traditionally, many operating systems and their underlying file system
>   implementations used 32-bit integers to represent file sizes and
>   positions. Consequently, no file could be larger than 2<sup>32</sup> − 1 bytes (4
>   GB − 1). In many implementations, the problem was exacerbated by
>   treating the sizes as signed numbers, which further lowered the limit
>   to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1 bytes (2 GB − 1).

Comment: Side note: Linux can use 64-bit file sizes and positions even on 32-bit since around a decade ago. Although it is not sure, that this pdf generator tool can use this functionality.

Comment: @peterh having 64-bit `off_t` won't help if the software tries to create the whole file in RAM and write it to disk in one go.

Comment: Linux doesn't treat sizes as signed, but the kernel needs some dedicated address space to function, and in the old days leaving 2GB to userland seemed like a lot, so the kernel would reserve the other 2GB.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Sizes are not signed, but pointer differences (`ptrdiff_t`) are, which mean effectively that sizes must be limited to the maximum (signed) value `ptrdiff_t` can represent, or else you get *really really nasty* UB and UB-related bugs that applications have no good way to work around.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev In that case the file won't have exactly 2GB-1 bytes, as the program need more memory to store things such as the executable code.

Comment: @R No it doesn't. There's no obligation to use `ptrdiff_t` in a program, one can simply access a huge array using an `uint32_t` index.

Comment: @user23013 The second part of what you said is true, but the amount of virtual memory available to a program and the size of the output file it can create are not really related. It's entirely possible there's a bug in ImageMagic, for example.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It's replied to "if the software tries to..." So "in that case".

Comment: @user23013 in my comment I was simply pointing out that having 64-bit file offsets doesn't guarantee that every program will handle large files correctly. Of course the actual maximum supported file size will depend on how exactly ImageMagic allocates RAM and handles the IO. Maybe the file being exactly 2GiB-1 bytes is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 12):

Try limiting the pixel cache used by `convert` to e.g. 1 GiB:

```
convert 0001.miff ... 2000.miff -limit memory 1GiB -limit map 1GiB -compress jpeg -quality 80 out.pdf
```

Hopefully this will force ImageMagic to regularly dump already processed data on the disk instead of trying to fit more than 2 GiB in RAM buffers.

BTW, the amount of virtual memory available to a single process on 32-bit Linux is defined by the `VMSPLIT` kernel config setting. This can be either 2G/2G (2GB for kernel + 2GB for userland) or 1G/3G (1 GB for kernel + 3 GB for userland). On a running system, the setting can be found via

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep VMSPLIT
```

On some systems the kernel config is stored in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't for the huge number of photographs you could use TeX/LaTeX to create the PDF. Then you can still get the same outcome (pdf of images) without the converter crash problem. The file limits on TeX should just be your system (hardware+OS)

But I think you could use a shell script to write the TeX:

0)

```
mkdir convert
pushd convert
PATH=convert:$PATH /* keep everything in one directory for tidyness.*/
```

1) make a template

1.1) I'm sure there's a way to do this step in one go, by replacing the image name with variable and inserting rather than appending, and to format $FOO to have the correct leading 0's, but the following is just what I know.

1.2) The template needs to split in order for the script to insert the file name

1.3) nano tmplt1 /* or editor of your choice*/

```
/* white space line */ 
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{
/* at this point the script will insert $FOO, the file name variable */
```

1.3.1) However, your files go 0001.miff … 0010.miff … 0100.miff … 2000.miff. Ie a variable number of leading zeros. Workaround: 4 versions of tmplt1: tmplt1-9, tmplt10-99, tmplt100-999, tmplt1000-2000. Tmplt1-9 ends “...width]{000” (ie add 3 0's); tmplt10-99 ends “...width]{00” (ie add 2 0's). 100-999 adds 1 zero and 1000-2000 is the same as tmplt1

1.4) next part of template: nano tmplt2 /* OEOYC */

```
.miff}
   \caption{ /* if you want to caption, otherwise skip to  tmplt3.
Same again, script will insert $FOO here */
```

1.5) next part of template: nano tmplt3 /* OEOYC */

```
}
\label{f:   /*if you want them labelled which is actually
a index/reference for the text to refer to, not a caption.
Same again, the script will insert $FOO here. If you do not
want labels, skip to tmplt4*/
```

1.6) next template: nano tmplt4 /* OEOYC */

```
    }
\end{figure}
```

2) make the begining of the file: nano head /* OEOYC */

```
\documentclass{article} /* Or more suitable class */
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
  /* white space line*/
```

3) make the end of file: nano foot /*OEOYC */

```
\end {document}
```

4) make the script: nano loader /* OEOYC */

```
#! /bin/bash

cat head > out.pdf

for FOO in {1...9}
do
    cat tmplt1-9 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt2 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt3 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt4 >> out.pdf
done

for FOO in {10...99}
do
    cat tmplt10-99 >> out.pdf /* this looks like a lot but
is actually copy-paste of first block, just add relevant 0's and 9's */
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt2 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt3 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt4 >> out.pdf
done

for FOO in {100...999}
do
    cat tmplt100-999 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt2 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt3 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt4 >> out.pdf
done

for FOO in {1000...2000}
do
    cat tmplt1000-2000 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt2 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt3 >> out.pdf
    echo "$FOO" | cat >> out.pdf
    cat tmplt4 >> out.pdf
done

cat foot >> out.pdf
```

5) make script executable: chmod u+x loader

5.1) After testing this, I found that every time $FOO was inserted, it was spread out over 3 lines. I don't know any workaround other than going into the script and manually deleting the carriage returns. At least it is only 36 for all 2000 photos

6) call script: loader

7) compile the TeX: pdflatex out.pdf